# How to implement end() for linked list?

Tags: c++, iterator

I am programming for class LinkedList for learning But I did't know what is the correct way to implement iterator `end()`. In case of begin() i pass the `Head` and i do like `Head = Head->next;` but `end()` will pointing to one past element to last so i can't pass `Tail` directly and iterate like `Tail = Tail->prev`.

1)what is the correct way  to implement iterator end() end function for linked list.

2)should i allocate a memory as dummy or i do some conditions in operator ++ and operator--?

3)How std::list do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The iterrator returned by end() should point to the end of your data structure (just after the last valid entry). [c++ Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)

In your case it should probably point to the last elements next pointer.
So for example:

```
LinkedList_Iterator_End(LinkedList<Type> *list)
{
    this->list  =   list;        //LinkesList<Type> *
    this->node_tmp  =   list->findLast();  //List<Type> *
    this->node = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: The last element's next pointer in a linked list is typically null.

Comment: Yes, the end Iterator is not meant to be dereferenced. [cpp ref end iterator][https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end].
And that way you can check if an iterator is an end iterator.

Comment: My point was that instead of taking the next pointer of the last node, you should just write `nullptr`. Also, that way it would also work for an empty list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer But how can i do operations like end()-- ?

Comment: end() should be a member function of your LinkedList, returning an end iterator.

Comment: i mean that how can i do operation like `std::list<int>::iterator i = n.end();
--i;` ( list is not empty ) now i is pointing to last element right?

Comment: Thats, why I added the node_tmp field, you can adjust the node to node_tmp.prev and node_tmp to node_tmp.prev .
You should implement this by overriding the -- operator in your iterator class.

Comment: Yes `i` will point to the last element of the list after the first `--i;`